Kotlin C interop (ffi): pin String in memory and deallocate manually
Recently I was playing around with the Kotlin native platform and the C Interoperability that offers.
I'm trying to wrap a rust library (that also makes use of the async-io, with the tokio runtime).
I have the following kotlin code:
override suspend fun rustFn(aString: String) {
    a_rust_fn(aString, fn)
}

companion object {
    private val fn = staticCFunction<ULong, Unit> { idx ->
        println("Callback $idx")
    }
}

I also have the rust code:
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn a_rust_fn(
    a_string: *const c_char,
    fun: unsafe extern "C" fn(idx: u64),
) {
    let a_string: &str = c_chars_to_str(a_string).unwrap();
    let runtime = RUNTIME.get().unwrap(); // get the tokio runtime from a static memory space
    runtime.spawn(async move {
        println!("{}", a_string); // Here the string is corrupted
        unsafe { fun(idx) }
    });
}

fn c_chars_to_str<'a>(c_chars: *const c_char) -> ResultCode<&'a str> {
    let c_str = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(c_chars) };
    let str = c_str.to_str().map_err(|_| INVALID_STRING_CONVERSION)?;
    Ok(str)
}

The problem is that inside the async move block the string is corrupted. It seems that the kotlin runtime has deallocated the memory at this point.
I wonder how I could "tell" to kotlin to keep in memory this String until I manually free it. Is there a way?
Of course I can make a copy of the string in the rust code (and thus resolve this issue):
let sql: String = c_chars_to_str(sql).unwrap().to_owned();

But, I was thinking if I could avoid this copy.

c_chars_to_str should be annotated unsafe. It shouldn't be possible to create a soundness problem using non-unsafe code; not having unsafe on c_chars_to_str enables this.
